# Facebook Sign In Segue Loads and Then Returns to Sign In Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parse-platform, swift2

So I have created a Sign In / Sign Up function using Parse and Swift.
After successful Facebook login the view controller I want to see pops up briefly but then the SignIn view controller comes back onto the screen. I want the user to be logged in and have access to the App. Why is this?

Below is my code for both view controllers. I have a storyboard with segues setup as shown below.

*fbSignIn - Facebook Sign In Segue*

*goSignIn - Sign In Page Segue*

**Main View Controller (The View Controller I want to go to after Facebook Login)**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

    } else {

// take user to SignInViewController through a custom segue
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goSignIn", sender: self)
}

}

@IBAction func logOutUser(sender: UIButton) {

    PFUser.logOut()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goSignIn", sender: self)

}
```

**Sign In View Controller (Sign In and Facebook Sign In Button)**

```
  @IBAction func didTapFacebookConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {

                print ("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbSignIn", sender: self)


            } else {
                print ("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbSignIn", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            print ("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbSignIn", sender: self)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Segue to your Facebook login page on a `viewDidAppear` method in your main viewcontroller. The behaviour you describe suggests that `PFUser.currentUser()` is `nil` so `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goSignIn", sender: self)` is executed in `viewDidAppear` when your main viewcontroller appears and you immediately end up back in the sign in page.

Comment: I need this though so when the user opens the App it checks to see if they are logged in and if not it then sends them to the Login Page. Is there any way I change this so that it does not effect my Facebook Login?

Comment: The behaviour you described, as far as I can see in your code, could happen when you have an unsuccessful Facebook login which means `PFUser.currentUser()` is nil. You perform a Segue to your main viewcontroller even if your login attempt failed which eventually takes you back to the login page. Why don't you just display an alert on login failure to the user and remain in the login viewcontroller ?

Comment: No it happens when the Login is successful. When successfully logged in using Facebook the Main View Controller pops up and then goes back to the Sign In View Controller. I want it to stay on the Main View Controller.

Comment: What is the value of PFUser.currentUser() in your viewDidAppear after a successful Facebook login ?

Comment: I am quite new to this so unsure of the lingo. That is all the code I have.